# ANT Java-Jar task to include native DLL

Tags: java, dll, ant, jar

I have a *JAR* library that needs a *native DLL library* to work properly (Scriptom/Jacob).

I added the *JARs* to my classpath in *ANT*. But I do not know how to add a *DLL file* so my compiled Java/Groovy files finds them (neither in a generated `JAR`, nor in an ordinary execution by `java Main.class`). They are all located in a project subdirectory `libs`.

How do I have to alter my ANT build file that DLLs are recognized by my application?

PS:

As it works properly in a configured Eclipse environment: Is it possible to extract a fully working ANT build file from an *Eclipse Run Configuration*?

Comment: When you unzip the jar, are your DLLs there?

Comment: Yes. I included them with a `<fileset>`, and could be found in the root folder after extracting.

Comment: ok. You can't use the DLLs when they're packaged in the .jar You will need to have them in say a folder, and load them from there in your application. See my answer below. if that works for you, mark it as the correct answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use DLL files when they're still packaged in the jar.

I suggest you create an application folder where your .jar will be located at and next to the  .jar, put your DLL files there. In your application you will need to load your DLLs from that location.

Comment: OK. I (ant)-moved the DLL files next to my application jar and added `static { System.load("PATH-TO-MY-DLL") }` to one of my classes. And now it works.